# Spring MockMvc verify body is empty

Tags: spring, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I have a simple Spring test

```
@Test
public void getAllUsers_AsPublic() throws Exception {
    doGet("/api/users").andExpect(status().isForbidden());
}

public ResultActions doGet(String url) throws Exception {
    return mockMvc.perform(get(url).header(header[0],header[1])).andDo(print());
}
```

I would like to verify that the response body is empty. E.g. Do something like `.andExpect(content().isEmpty())`

Answer (score 72, accepted):

There's a cleaner way:

```
andExpect(jsonPath("$").doesNotExist())
```

Note that you can't use `isEmpty` because it checks for an empty value, and assumes the existence of the attribute. When the attribute doesn't exist, `isEmpty` throws an exception. Whereas, `doesNotExist` verifies that the attribute doesn't exist, and when used with `$`, it checks for an empty JSON document.

Comment: One caveat is that `andExpect(jsonPath("$").doesNotExist())` will silently succeed when the content body exists and contains the string `null` (without quotes), which may or may not be what you want. I tested this on version 2.4.0.

Comment: @ChrisH. Interesting, but an edge case. `null` gets special treatment in JSON, so if all the attributes have the value `null`, an argument can be made that it’s as good as empty. As a developer, I’d question the design rather than the behavior; why’d anyone include `null` attributes, other than to confuse clients. Most JSON libraries, like Jackson, have the option to omit writing out `null` attributes.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar - I'm getting "java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path $" when applied to a non-JSON response.

Comment: @wh81752 that’s like saying there’s something wrong with the hammer because you can’t tighten a screw with it. Instead of hijacking this thread, I recommend opening a new question.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar - you are on the right track with hammer and screw. Because your "JSON" hammer does not fit the *any* content screw. Your answer assumes JSON as content-type which is not justified given the original question. Btw, see my answer below for a more generic solution.

Comment: .andExpect(status().isNoContent()) should be good enough.

Answer (score 18):

I think one of these options should achieve what you're looking for, although not quite as nice as an `isEmpty()` (from the [ContentResultMatchers documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/ContentResultMatchers.html)):

```
.andExpect(content().bytes(new Byte[0])
```

or

```
.andExpect(content().string(""))
```

Comment: I'm surprised this ever worked @DaveyDaveDave. I tried this with version 2.2.4.RELEASE of Spring Boot (with managed dependencies from `spring-boot-starter-parent`) with a response with no body. Abhijit's answer works. The string approach from your answer yields `Response content expected:<> but was:<null>`. Then if you use `.string( (String) null)` you get `Response content expected:<null> but was:<null>`. Huh??? The bytes approach from your answer yields `Response content expected:<{}> but was:<{110, 117, 108, 108}>` (which is puzzling because MockHttpServletResponse logs Body = `null`).

Comment: I see. The [ASCII values](http://www.asciitable.com/) 110, 117 and 108 are "n", "u" and "l" respectively. What you have is a response containing the literal word "null", not an empty response. I suspect `.andExpect(content().string("null"))` will pass.

Comment: You are correct @DaveyDaveDave, and thank you. Funny I missed that. In this case, the fact that the expectation for `jsonPath("$").doesNotExist()` does not fail is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest to use either (A) or (B)

```
import org.hamcrest.Matchers;
...
mockMvc.perform(..)
  .andExpect(content().string(Matchers.blankOrNullString())) // (A)
  .andExpect(content().string(Matchers.blankString()))       // (B)
```

Tested with hamcrest:2.2